# Regex to remove html does not get rid of img tag

Tags: java, html-parsing

I am using a regex to remove HTML tags. I do something like - 
    result.replaceAll("\<.*?\>", "");

However, it does not help me get rid of the img tags in the html. Any idea what is a good way to do that?

Comment: For the love of all things kind and sane do not Regex HTML - Use a parser, please.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail. I'd think that something like `<img src="ping.png">` should be removed with your regex.

Comment: What happens if the html contains something like `<span>x < 7</span>`? You can't parse/process HTML with a regex. See this answer for why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Comment: @Marc B, that isn't a valid example, since you would need to escape the < using &lt;

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr:  I agree that *parsing* HTML with regexes is impossible (by the pumping lemma), but he is just doing a lexical analysis which is a regular language (ie just separate out the tokens).  There is no reason why regexes would not work in this case.

Comment: @Mikola -- See Marc B's comment above. Rarely is HTML Valid, it's not XHTML.

Comment: In HTML, < is not a valid token, unless it appears in a tag.  If you fed that into any browser it would barf.  EDIT:  Actually, I just tried it and apparently firefox actually parses it anyway, even though it isn't a valid document.  Go figure...

Comment: @Mikola Actually there is a simple counterexample: `<img src="ping.png" alt=">>>ALT>>>"/>`. It really isn't a good idea to use regex for something like HTML.

Comment: @Howard:  Ok, I buy that example.

Comment: @Mikola: That's why you can't parse HTML with a regex with any form of reliability: You know > isn't valid unless it's encoded, we know it's not valid unless it's encoded. The rest of the world couldn't care less because their browser renders it "right" anyways.

Comment: From my painful experience - if you are using regular expressions to process HTML, don't.  HTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be parsed by regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a more concrete recommendation, use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) (or [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/)) to parse the HTML into a Java object.

Once you've got a `Document` object it can easily be traversed to remove the tags.  This [cookbook recipe](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) shows how to get attributes and text from the DOM.

Comment: I had a look at JSoup before, but its pretty huge. I need a small lightweight library, or code.

Comment: NekoHTML is another option, and Thor has mentioned HTMLCleaner.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use HTML parsers/cleaners then I would at least suggest you to use `Pattern.DOTALL` flag to take care of multi-line HTML blocks. Consider code like this:

```
String str = "123 <img \nsrc='ping.png'>abd foo";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("<.*?>", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pt.matcher(str);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "");
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println("Output: " + sb);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Output: 123 abd foo
```

Comment: What if you try this on the example Howard posted?           <img src=">foo<.jpg">

Comment: @Mikola: Even I have recommended against Regex in my answer. I have answered this because OP was insisting on using simple regex. HTML is so irregular that any regex will fail to take care of those fringe cases.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion is [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

use html parser instead. iterate over the object, print however you like and get the best result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just re-iterating what others have said already, but this point cannot be over-stated: DO NOT USE REGEXES TO PARSE HTML. There are a 1,000 similar questions on this on SO. Use a proper HTML parser, it will make your life so much easier, and is far more robust and reliable. Take a look at Dom4j, Jericho, JSoup. Please.

Answer (score 0):

So, a piece of code for you.
I use http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/ to parse HTML. It is not overcomplicated and quite straightforward to use.

Basically it looks like this:

```
import org.htmlparser.Parser;
import org.htmlparser.util.NodeList;
import org.htmlparser.util.ParserException;

    ...

    String html; /* read your HTML into variable 'html' */
    String result=null;
    ....
    try {
        Parser p = new Parser(html);
        NodeList nodes = p.parse(null);
        result = nodes.asString();
    } catch (ParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

That will give you plain text stripped of tags (but no substitutes like **&amp;** would be fixed). And of course you can do plenty more with this library, like applying filters, visitors, iterating and all the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able achieve do this with the below code snippet.

```
String htmlContent = values.get(position).getContentSnippet();
String plainTextContent = htmlContent.replaceAll("<img .*?/>", "");
```

I used the above regex to clean the img tags in my RSS content.